# How to get inner text under span id

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I am working on a vba web automation project . I have come to a point where I have to get the message displayed on the web form in excel sheet. The HTML codes of the relevent section are as follows.

```html
 <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMsg" style="color: red; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold;">Name or Father Name or Mother Name or Date of Birth already Exists.</span>
```

I have tried following codes but could not get any result

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3").Range("cs&y").Value = ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMsg").getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
```

I want to get  "Name or Father Name or Mother Name or Date of Birth already Exists" as result

Answer (score 3):

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3").Range("cs&y").Value = ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMsg").innertext
```

Comment: Thanx for so prompt response but it is not working.

Comment: Can you check your range name, I think that is not valid ".Range("cs&y")

Comment: Try to put it to messagebox to test like this: "msgbox ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMsg").innertext"

Comment: Take any value for range such as "D2"